# Using assign instead of subscribe in kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, librdkafka

I have two different applications with different consumers ids & group ids as below.

```
Application 1 : 
Consumer id = consumer-1
Consumer group id = consumer-group-1

Application 2 : 
Consumer id = consumer-2
Consumer group id = consumer-group-2
```

Both consumer-1 & consumer-2 is manually assigned to the same topic partition (lets say topic name = test & partition id = 0) and are consuming messages independently. Now my question is that, since `assign()` will loose control over dynamic partition assignment and consumer group coordination, how Kafka stores/identifies the last committed offset for consumer-1 & consumer-2. Sometimes I see commit failures with message as below.

```
{"severity":4,"fac":"COMMITFAIL","message":"[thrd:main]: Offset commit (cgrp auto commit timer) failed for 0/1 partition(s): test[0]@8747(Broker: Unknown member)"}
```

Is this because I'm using two different consumers (in two different applications) manually assigned to a same topic & partition id? Is it allowed to use two consumers manually assigned to a same topic & partition?

Also I suspected whether my consumer's max poll/session timeout interval may be too small. But for testing I commented all of my processing logic so that I just consume and write a log, but still I see the above commit fail error.

Comment: Please share your consumer code and config

Comment: I figured out the issue. Issue is that, two consumers using same client id. Updated the client id to be unique and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Could you please explain more about your solution @Raaj, I just have the same issue as you